# gameObject rotation in Unity issue?

Tags: unity

Can someone provide me with a script that makes a gamebject calculate its rotation speed based on the next collision, in a way that when it collides, it collides with its original rotation.

I do not want the cube to abruptly return to its original rotation once it has collided with something. Like in the video, the cube's rotation is just right when it collides (when it hits the ground, it feels natural). I have tried many times fine tuning the rotation, but I always fail to get it just right (+predicting future collisions is unknown to me). I do not have the experience to accomplish such a task and searching the Web did not help either. I would appreciate any lines of code, guidance or help from the community. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do not cross post on multiple SE sites. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465687/gameobject-rotation-in-unity-issue

Comment: With all respect, I am cross-posting because I lack answers.

Comment: @Almo This behavior is totally acceptable since he has not received any answers. Also, this is an excellent question because it will definitely help future game developers. And it's well written, with obvious research effort.

Comment: It should only be on one or the other site. I've never been told it's "acceptable behavior" to cross post duplicate questions across multiple SE sites.

Comment: I can't say i clearly understood the question, may be because of my english level. Can you make it more simple, so users like me can understand too?

Comment: It is not acceptable to cross-post between SE sites.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an [inter-network cross post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465687/gameobject-rotation-in-unity-issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it looks like rotation issue, it's actually animation issue. You'd typically have a jump animation where the character is jumping and you'd add sprites for frames in the cycle. Since in such scenarios, the jump height,distance and duration is fixed, the rotation will always be the same.

Comment: In my case, the jump height, distance and duration are not fixed. So, animation would be useless for me.

Comment: Even if they are not fixed, there is a way to solve it through animation. For example, you can set frames with "y" velocity as condition. So depending on velocity, the character will animate appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's a nice idea. Can you show me how exactly? I don't know how to accomplish such a task.

Comment: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/2d-controllers  That is official Unity video. The video deals with building 2D animations from sprites and implementing them with the Mecanim animation system. They have discussed animation for Jump and double jump

Comment: My project is not 2D, it's 3D.

Comment: Sorry. Watched the attached video and thought it was 2D.

Comment: No worries... :)

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have experience with 3D :)